# Is there a way to crawl only a specific list within one site collection?

Tags: 2010, search, crawl, enterprise

We have:
 - one specific List that needs to be indexed every 10 minutes
   http://site/lists/Invoices
 - several archived lists:
   http://site/lists/archved1, http://site/lists/archved2, etc that need to be crawled only once a week.

I want to have one search content source for each of these cases with separate schedules. Unfortunately, I've found out that it's not that easy as I thought.

I don't think crawl rules is an option since they will apply for the whole website.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing Scopes (or Result Sources in 2013) with Content Sources. Each content source is crawled Full, Incremental, or Continuously and is based on the "start address". In your case I would configure a continuous crawl in SP 2013. By default the changed content is re-indexed every 15 minutes.

As for Result Sources (or Scopes) they are used to segment your index, in your case you could create a Result Source for Invoices that only returned results from your target List or Library.

If you only have 2010 you do not have as much capability for indexing. Your only choice would be to create a new Web App with a target site collection that you can schedule separately from the other web apps. Though I think this would be over-kill.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew, I've corrected the question. I meant content sources, of course, not scopes. I want to accept your question, but I am not sure about the part about Result Sources. Are you saying that that it is possible in SP2013 to crawl Result Sources within one site collection based on different schedules?

Comment: No, the schedules are only based on Content Sources. To maintain the freshness your desire I would suggest Continuous Crawling of the Content Source that contains the List (of course you can use Continuous Crawling for all your SharePoint content, too.) Then use a Result Source for segmenting the results as part of your solution.

Comment: Matthew, I've accepted your answer. But to make it more clear for the others, I would just say: "No, this is impossible" and would not mention continuous crawl at all. Continious crawl does not solve my problem for the following reason: 1) I need to crawl archived lists once a week. 2) Need to crawl the current list every 10 minutes. I can't use continuous crawl for two reasons: a) it's SP2010 b) it will slow down my SharePoint Application even further. This is the exact problem I want to solve

Comment: If you use SharePoint 2013 and create a Search Center, you can crawl 2010 continuously. I am just trying to recommend solutions and options.